# Does Facebook XMPP Chat server implement message archiving? (XEP-0136)

Tags: facebook, xmpp

I'm working with Facebook's XMPP chat service, and I need to fetch older messages from the server. Can I use XEP-0136 on the client to do that or is there another more used way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out myself Facebook does not implement that feature. I got this reply sending an IQ:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='chat.facebook.com' to='my.facebook.username@chat.facebook.com/Mac-Pro-di-Michele_65563c5f_4D689E59FB8A5' type='error' id='pref1'>
  <pref xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'/>
  <error code='501' type='cancel'>
    <feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no way of knowing and most likely it does not support because facebook is not xmpp compliant. majority of xmpp servers do not support this feature.